Make class property nullable when condition is false
I created a service that retrieves users from the database with a one-to-one relationship and so I have this ApplicationUser class
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public required int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Username { get; set; }
    public required string ProfilePicture { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public UserProfile? Profile { get; set; }
}

And this is the service function
public async Task<ApplicationUser?> GetByUserIdAsync(int userId, bool includeProfile = false)
{
    IQueryable<ApplicationUser> query = _dbContext.Users;

    if (includeProfile)
    {
        query.Include(u => u.Profile);
    }
    
    return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
}

As you can see I added a argument includeProfile so that when I also need the user profile I can tell the function to include it.
The issue lies in the return type. Since ApplicationUser.Profile is nullable, when I access that property in my code even if I pass true for includeProfile, I get the warning that Profile could be null.
So my question is: How do I make it so that when includeProfile is true, ApplicationUser.Profile is not null?

You would have to change to property to be not nullable. However then you would need  set a value for all the null values in the database if any.

But i want it to be nullable if includeProfile is false so setting it to not nullable wouldn't work.

No, the nullability of a property type cannot be dynamic - it's part of the class metadata.
In your code, you are not actually accessing the property, just identifying a property through an expression that the context uses to include child properties.  So you can either ignore the warning or disable the warning in this class file.
For users of the class, they may have no idea whether includeProfile was true or not when the object was created, so they will need to check for nulls as appropriate. If a user is certain that the objects they are using will have a profile, then they can choose to disable the warning as well.

Boolean parameters are usually discouraged, as method calls are less readable. Consider, these two calls:
var user1 = GetByUserIdAsync(5, true);
var user2 = GetByUserIdAsync(5, false);

As a developer, reading those two lines, it's impossible to tell the difference between what they do, without looking into how GetByUserIdAsync is implemented.
Specialized methods
Instead, I'd recommend you add a method for each action and a data type that more clearly tells the difference (I don't know the details of your system so you might have better names for it):
// Data types
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public required int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Username { get; set; }
    public required string ProfilePicture { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}

public class UserDetails : ApplicationUser
{
    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

// Methods
public async Task<ApplicationUser?> GetByUserIdAsync(int userId)
{
    return await _dbContext.Users
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
}

public async Task<UserDetails?> GetDetailsByUserIdAsync(int userId)
{
    // You might need some mapping to a 'UserDetails'
    return await _dbContext.Users
        .Include(u => u.Profile)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
}

// Calls
var user = GetByUserIdAsync(5);
var userDetails = GetDetailsByUserIdAsync(5);

Now, it's more clear from the names of the classes what they contain as well as the names of the methods. You don't really need to look into the implementation to know the outcome of the calls at the bottom. At the same time you eliminate the if-statement, reducing the complexity (granted, it's not a complex method to begin with).

As a workaround for that "bool parameter problem" : you can mention the parameter name as getByUserIdAsync(5, includeProfile: true)

@HansKeﬆing True, but that information isn't passed on after the method call and in this case the result of setting the bool isn't reflected in the return type and thus lost further up in the call hierarchy. I'd say there's usually a better solution than this workaround.
